# Product a scalar with a matrix in mathematica

Tags: matrix, wolfram-mathematica, product, scalar

I want to product a scalar with a matrix in mathematica. My codes are :

`w.P + (w^3).P`

P is a matrix and w is a scalar, but product gives scalar out of the matrix. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.` operator is specifically for tensor (including vector and matrix) multiplication.  Just multiply without the `.`:

```
w P + (w^3) P
```

I can't explain your statement that the product as you have it yields a scalar.  For example:

```
P = {{1, 2}, {2, 3}};
w = 5;
w.P
```

Gives the result:

```
5.{{1, 2}, {2, 3}};
```

since *Mathematica* hasn't defined what `Dot[a, b]` means when `a` is a scalar and `b` is a matrix.  (You could actually define this yourself if you like.)

Comment: the same result was given by mathematica. w is fractional number like 4.8634 and matrix 3x3. but w is out of the matrix when 'w P + (w^3) P'

Comment: Can you provide a minimal complete example that I can try?

Comment: w=4.81048 and P=MatrixForm[{0,0,0},{0,0,0},{0,0,1}]  like this. wP=4.81048MatrixForm[{0,0,0},{0,0,0},{0,0,1}] when I do it in mathematica. I want to MatrixForm[{0,0,0},{0,0,0},{0,0,4.81048}]

Comment: `MatrixForm` doesn't yield a matrix, it's a directive to output a matrix in a certain way.  Remove it and try this: `P = {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}; w = 4.81048; w P`  Notice the space between the `w` and the `P`, it doesn't look like you have that in you comment, but perhaps that was just a typo.

Comment: Thank you so much Codie, your suggestions solved the problem :) but it gives a result like this P = {{0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 4.81048}} why it added a dot on the right side of each elements of matrix.

Comment: That's because w is a `Real`, and the elements were type `Integer`.  Mathematica will make a `Real` times and `Integer` a `Real`.  so `0 4.81048` yields `0.`.   Glad I could help!